# How to hide/show columns with material-ui table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using http://www.material-ui.com, Is it possible to hide/show columns based on the device? For example, on desktop, I want to show 6 columns but on a phone, I might want to show 3 specific columns. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a CSS `className` on the corresponding `TableHeaderColumn` and `TableRowColumn` elements that is hidden/shown depending on a CSS `@media` query.

For convenience sake, I'm using Bootstrap below and its "hidden-xs" CSS class, which provides such a media query. You'll see that the "Status" column is hidden when you resize the browser window below a certain width.

https://jsfiddle.net/2uepwbd9/1/

```
class Example extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn className="hidden-xs">Status</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn className="hidden-xs">Employed</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn className="hidden-xs">Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>Stephanie Sanders</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn className="hidden-xs">Employed</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>Steve Brown</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn className="hidden-xs">Employed</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know I am late but this answer is for someone who wants to do it with only material-ui.
Material-ui provides [theme breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#breakpoints) and [withWidth](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#withwidth-) HOC. Both of them can be used to show/hide columns on device size. 
Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zyrym47o4) of using theme breakpoints to change styles based on device width. Same concept can be used to hide/show columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a grid library like [reflexbox](http://jxnblk.com/reflexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a Hidden component that does exactly what you're asking for. [See the documentation](https://material-ui.com/layout/hidden/).