# how to show/hide a <div> with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to do something really simple : using material-ui, I would like to have an `<p>Info</p>` tag and when I click it, it unrolls a `<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>` text. This is a simple toggle section.

I did some researches on the official website https://material-ui.com/ but I didn't find.
Using [hidden](https://material-ui.com/components/hidden/) doesn't seems appropriate (right ?).
Do you know how to do it (is there a material-ui functionnality to do it) ? I'm using React.js
[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475108/how-to-hide-show-columns-with-material-ui-table) didn't help me.

Thanks in advance for your help,
I hope this will be usefull to some people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with the [collapse](https://material-ui.com/components/transitions/#collapse) component.

```js
       <Collapse in={checked}>
          <YourComponentToShowAndHide />
        </Collapse>
```